# How to make the width of parent div equal to the width of child image, and height of child image to height of the parent div using CSS only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML along with twitter bootstrap

```
<div class="img-container clearfix">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="/path/to/img.img">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="/path/to/img.img">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="/path/to/img.img">
  </div>
  <!-- And so on.... -->
</div>
```

and following CSS

```
<style>
  div.img-container {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.img-container > .image {

      width: auto;
      height: 50%;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px;
      opacity: 1;
  }
  div.img-container > .image > img {

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

The height of the image is getting adjusted to the height of the parent div `div.image`, at the same time i want the parent div `div.image` to get the same width of the child image, so that all the images look equally spaced.

seems to work ok in chrome, but not working in firefox, below is the link of the same in codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPwWrV

the following is the screenshot too
[image]

Please help me out regarding the same...

Comment: It works in Firefox for me. What issue do you get with Firefox?

Comment: somehow the width of the div is more than the width of the Image, and also in chrome, i see the same problem when i resize the browser.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question reg the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug that seems to come from padding + bootstrap. remove one or the other and it is gone.

You may set the padding to the inner image :

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

div.img-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.img-container > .image {
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1;
}

div.img-container > .image > img {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue, inset 0 0 3px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pJwgRP